# nth-child(even) not applying to my css selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a gallery container which has two columns. I append multiple photos to the container using jQuery. When I attempt to use nth-child(n) on the div container or img tags, nothing happens. I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried to use nth-of-type too, selecting image tags, div tags, adding classes and IDs trying to get it to access the elements, but I've failed each time.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="photos"></div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
$( ".photos" ).append(`<img class=\"diaryImage\" src=\"..url\">`);
```

CSS:

```
.photos {
 line-height: 0;
-webkit-column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-gap:   0px;
-moz-column-count:    2;
-moz-column-gap:      0px;
column-count:         2;
column-gap:           0px;

margin-top:.5%;
background-color: transparent;
width: 80%;
margin-left: 16%;
height: auto;
overflow: auto;

}

.photos img {
width: 100% !important;
height: auto !important;
vertical-align: top;
}

.photos img:nth-child(even) {
width: 10%;
/*    grid-column:2;*/
}
```

I have also tried:

```
div.photos img:nth-child(even) {
width: 10%;
/*    grid-column:2;*/
}

.photos:nth-child(even) {
width: 10%;
/*    grid-column:2;*/
}
```

And a couple of other tags. I'm new to using nth child selectors so not 100% sure what I'm doing wrong.

I just want any impact to be had on every second photo. Once I can see the selector working, I can continue working on the problem. My ultimate objective is to have every second photo placed into column 2, but just testing with width:10%; to see if the code is having any impact.

Comment: Can you please build a runnable snippet? Makes troubleshooting FAR easier....

Comment: Will do! I'll upload one as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see a problem with `:nth-child(even)`, see below, it works as expected, Your issue is coming from the use of `!important` as stated in the other answer from @Trevin Avery.

Futhermore why are you escaping this:

```js
.append(`<img class=\"diaryImage\" src=\"..url\">`);
```

This

```js
.append(`<img class="diaryImage" src="${dynamic_url}" />`);
```

should work with issues, no?

```css
.photos img:nth-child(even) {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="photos">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=1" alt="" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=2" alt="" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=3" alt="" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=4" alt="" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=5" alt="" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=6" alt="" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=7" alt="" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200?text=8" alt="" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: $( ".photos" ).append(`<img class=\"diaryImage\" src=\"${temp_url}\">`); Apologies. This is what the actual code looks like. The escaped tag is so I can use ${} to easily use image source from my backend.

Comment: Oh apparently it was working all along. It seems for some reason, I cannot override the width. I tried with the border, and it worked perfectly. Strange! Thank you!

Comment: see @Trevin Avery's answer for the why you can't override the width, it's because you use `!important`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have `!important` in `.photos img`. Remove that and it will work as expected.

`!important` will override all other styles that are trying to set that attribute, even if they are more specific, unless they also have an `!important`. This is preventing the new style in `.photos img:nth-child(even)` from being applied.

[Here's the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) and [here's a helpful tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/).

Comment: yap, he's right, exactly why !important is usually a bad idea =)!

Comment: Avoid `!important` whenever possible!

Comment: Wow I didn't know that! Thanks so much! You learn something new every day.